# BackboneJs Collections and Rest API calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, require

I am currently working on a blog in backbone - now previously to this any backbone app I created has been fairly small so i should fetch all my collection on the initialisation on the app, store it in collections and pass them collections through to my view for usage.

I am faced with dealing with potentially a large amount of data (Blog Posts). I don't believe loading all that data in one call is the best idea. What i would like to do is create paginate that would initially request say 9 records with the post count and current page of the count and then for each page we make a new request for the next set of data etc.

Keep in mind I am also building the Rest API along with it so i don't have any restraints regarding the format of the response.

I would very much like to do this still following the collections concept in backbone - is this possible?

If anyone has done this before or has any idea that could help me out then it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var BlogPostsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function() {
        return 'posts?page='+this.page;
    },

    fetch: function(options) {
        this.page = options && options.page || 0;

        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    parse: function(resp, options) {
        var models = resp;

        return _.map(models, function(model) {
            model.page = options.page;
            return model;
        });
    }

});

var BlogPostsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    syncedPages: [],

    events: {
        'click .page': 'onPageClick'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.filteredCollection = new Backbone.Collection();

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'request', this.onCollectionRequest);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onCollectionSync);
        this.listenTo(this.filteredCollection, 'reset', this.onFilteredCollectionReset);

        this.requestingPage = 0;
        this.collection.fetch({
            page: this.requestingPage
        });

        this.render();
    },

    onPageClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.requestingPage = +e.target.dataset.page;

        if (this.syncedPages.indexOf(this.requestingPage) < 0) {
            this.collection.fetch({
                page: this.requestingPage,
                remove: false // Important - merge the response models
            });
        } else {
            this.filterToPage(this.requestingPage);
        }
    },

    onCollectionRequest: function() {
        this.filteredCollection.reset();
        this.render();
    },

    onCollectionSync: function(collection, response, options) {
        if (options.page === this.requestingPage) {
            this.filterToPage(this.requestingPage);
        }

        this.syncedPages.push(options.page);
    },

    onFilteredCollectionReset: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    filterToPage: function(page) {
        this.currentPage = page;
        this.filteredCollection.reset(this.collection.where({ page: page }));
    },

    render: function() {
        if (!this.filteredCollection.length) {
            this.$el.html('<p>Loading...</p>')
        } else {
            this.$el.empty();
            this.filteredCollection.each(function(postModel) {
                this.$el.append('<p>'+postModel.get('title')+'</p>');
            }, this);
        }

        this.$el.append('<a href="#page0" class="page" data-page="0">Page 0</a> | <a href="#page1" class="page" data-page="1">Page 1</a>');
    }

});

var blogPostView = new BlogPostsView({
    el: $('#app'),
    collection: new BlogPostsCollection()
});
```

Obviously the view is for demo purposes - using html strings, appending of blog posts one-by-one is suboptimal, there should be a BlogPostView and a BlogNavigationView etc.

Note I've added some bonus logic:

- After a page has been fetched, it doesn't need to re-fetch it (remove:false + syncedPages)
- If multiple requests occur it doesn't get confused about which to display (due to requestingPage variable). If you click on Page 1, then back to Page 0, it will instantly display Page 0 again, but it will have cached Page 1 in the background.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/sfyqt7wr/